# Flutter webview scaffold. update url after barcode

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter. I am having webview scaffold in the body section.

My objective is to scan the barcode (URL) and update the webview link. I could able to initialize webview scaffold, and scan the barcode and get the URL. when I update the set state, it did not update the webview. Any suggestion on this ?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_barcode_scanner/flutter_barcode_scanner.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _barcodedata ="";
  String getcode ="";
  String urllink ="https://www.google.com";
  Future scanbarcode() async{
    getcode = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode("#009922", "CANCEL", true, ScanMode.DEFAULT);
    setState(() {
      _barcodedata = getcode;
      urllink =getcode;
    });
    print (getcode);
    print(_barcodedata);
    print(urllink);
    print('Done1');
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Hello"),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.scanner),
              onPressed: (){
                scanbarcode();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: WebviewScaffold(
          url: urllink,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try to put `scanbarcode()` inside `initState()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
I only remark some part of scan and return a fix url 
you need `FlutterWebviewPlugin flutterWebviewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();`
and use `flutterWebviewPlugin.reloadUrl(urlString);`

working demo 
click scan button from flutter change to microsoft

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:flutter_barcode_scanner/flutter_barcode_scanner.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: WebViewExample(),
    );
  }
}

class WebViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WebViewExampleState createState() => _WebViewExampleState();
}

class _WebViewExampleState extends State<WebViewExample> {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  FlutterWebviewPlugin flutterWebviewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();
  var urlString = "https://google.com";

  launchUrl() {
    setState(() {
      urlString = controller.text;
      flutterWebviewPlugin.reloadUrl(urlString);
    });
  }

  Future scanbarcode() async{
    /*getcode = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode("#009922", "CANCEL", true, ScanMode.DEFAULT);
    setState(() {
      _barcodedata = getcode;
      urllink =getcode;
    });
    print (getcode);
    print(_barcodedata);
    print(urllink);
    print('Done1');*/
    urlString = "https://www.microsoft.com";
    flutterWebviewPlugin.reloadUrl(urlString);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    flutterWebviewPlugin.onStateChanged.listen((WebViewStateChanged wvs) {
      print(wvs.type);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebviewScaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Hello"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.scanner),
            onPressed: () => scanbarcode(),
          )
        ],
      ),
      url: urlString,
      withZoom: false,
    );
  }
}
```